# cannot import name 'asanyarray'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm currently having trouble importing some simple packages.
I'm working on pycharm professional in a virtual environment.

just trying to load;

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
from sklearn.ensemble._iforest import _average_path_length
import shap
```

```
importError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-1-5b7f1bf909af> in <module>
----> 1 import pandas as pd
      2 import numpy as np
      3 from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
      4 from sklearn.ensemble._iforest import _average_path_length
      5 import shap

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>
     14 
     15 if missing_dependencies:
---> 16     raise ImportError(
     17         "Unable to import required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(missing_dependencies)
     18     )

ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: cannot import name 'asanyarray' from 'numpy.core.multiarray' (C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py
```

I've never come across this error before so don't know how to fix.

Comment: " I'm working on pycharm professional in a virtual environment." How exactly did you install pandas and numpy *for that virtual environment*?

Comment: I'm guessing you might have incompatible versions of pandas and numpy, but it can be a number of reasons. There are not enough details

Comment: I installed the packages via the package installer in pycharm.

Comment: As @SurDin comment, try to install other versions of that from within PyCharm, on the desired env. Be sure that you have installed on the desired env. Be sure that the desired env is chosen for the test. One of the problems that I have faced to due to my insufficient experience using PyCharm was that: I have set my desired env as the default PyCharm env but it was not set and PyCharm was started with another env each time, on which my libs was not installed, and I had to select the desired env from bottom-right side each time.  If all fails, try uninstall and reinstall it from outside PyCharm.